# Redefine \subref after redefinition of \ref

Tags: cross-referencing, subcaption

I have redefined `\ref` like this:

```
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\autoref{#1}}
```

so that I get "Figure nn" automatically by default.

However, this makes `\subref` (from package `subcaption`) behave incorrectly.

How can `\subref` be redefined to get its correct behavior while keeping the redefined behavior of `\ref`?

Comment: Use `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\autoref{#1}}}` However I have the feeling that this redefinition isn't a good idea.

Comment: That is what I am doing and causes trouble when using `\subref` (these are not rendered correctly). Somewhat there is some interference doing that and later using `\subref`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by quitting on redefining the `\ref`. So I am now using `\autoref` directly and `\subref` is working properly.